# Orchard CMS web Themes Aside not in the Aside .. why

Tags: asp.net-mvc, themes, orchardcms

I am using the ThemeMachine and also trying the CustomThemeMachne themes - they reveal I should have an aside1, 2, and 3 .. I was under the impression that Aside was Aside of the main content and not underneath the main content; and that is where they show up now - right under the main content. What I would like to have is my Aside1 to the Left Side of the Entire Page for various content such as article links and Adverts and also an Aside on the Right side of the Entire Page. See the picture below where RED Rectangle is the page menu / main content / etc , the Blue rectangles are the Aside 1 and Aside 3

I am having some difficulty in figuring out how to do that - since I am really new to Orchard and my skill sets with MVC model are limited.

I would like some guidance or an example of exactly how I can accomplish this with either of these two themes after an example or really good info I feel I will be able to figure out what I need to do.

[image: Aside 1 and Aside 2]

Answer (score 0):

The rectangles are called zones. These are defined in the `Theme.txt`. Search for a line that starts with `Zones:`, it states each zone in a simple comma separated list, for example:

`Zones: Navigation, Content, UserDisplayName, ...`

The actual render order of the zones is defined by HTML markup in the `Layout.cshtml`, for example:

```
@{
  Func<dynamic, dynamic> Zone = x => Display(x); // Zone as an alias for Display to help make it obvious when we're displaying zones
}

<div>
  <div>
    You are logged in as @Zone(New.UserDisplayName())
  </div>

  <nav>
    @Zone(Model.Navigation)
  </nav>

  <div>
    @Zone(Model.Content)
  </div>
</div>
```

This is all well documented at http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Anatomy-of-a-theme/